# How do I create per page and per category stylesheets in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create many different skins that apply depending on the page and the category of my Wordpress site. I am not sure of two things:

1. How to use an or statement in PHP to call on the skin1.css stylesheet if `is_page('x')` OR if `is_category('1')`. (On that note, how do you specify multiple pages and/or categories in the same line?
2. Why is the following code displaying as text in the header of my web site?
3. There must be a better way to write these if else statements. Any tips?

I know this is a mess.

```
    < ?php if (is_page( 'health' ) ) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/skins/health-skin.css" />
    < ?php } elseif (is_page( 'beauty' ) ) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/skins/beauty-skin.css" />
    < ?php } elseif (is_page( 'home' ) ) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/skins/home-skin.css" />
    < ?php } elseif (is_page( 'food' ) ) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/skins/food-skin.css" />
    < ?php } elseif (is_page( 'travel' ) ) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/skins/travel-skin.css" />
    < ?php } else { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/skins/default-skin.css" />
    < ?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ok, so while I wait for an answer, I'm continuing to Google around. I've changed my code to the following: http://pastebin.com/ipK8e1fC

Am I on the right track?

EDIT: Clearly not the solution. I get the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or '; on line 48.

I'll continue to work it out while I wait for an answer.

Comment: in your pastebin you should change your `'` `"` statements inside the echo string, it is missleading php what opens and closes the string :) what about `"\""` same error you would get with javascript

Comment: Are you saying to convert ALL ' to " or just the ones wrapped around the stylesheet line following the echo?

Comment: as far as i remember my old php times.. it should be so `echo '<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"'.bloginfo('template_url').'\"/css/skins/health-skin.css\" />';` and quicker php if you have a lot bloginfo calls to use variables `$tricky=bloginfo('template_url');` and build your string with it like `echo "bla".$tricky."bla";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got this to work.

Originally I had used `is_page('x')` and then switched to `is_category('x')`.

That worked for the categories, explicitly. When a post belonging to one of those categories was visited, the stylesheet defaulted back to the original setting.

It took some time and reading, but I found something that worked quite well (and looks prettier with the use of arrays).

```
 <?php if ( !is_home() && in_category( array( 'health-fitness', 'fitness', 'health-fitness-blogs', 'menopause', 'nutrition', 'vitaminminerals-chart', 'weight-management', 'health' ) )) { ?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/skins/health-skin.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <?php } ?>
```

I added the `!is_home()` because something was throwing off my home page from the default setting and pulling in a specific stylesheet. I'm wondering if because the home page was the "front" page for the content that the `in_category('x')` was registering some of the excerpts as part of those equations.

It's just a guess. I don't actually know, but that seemed to resolve the issue so far.

Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
&&  //=and
||  //=or
!== //=not same as
!   //=not
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

Comment: Another option would be to have a single style sheet with rules that target particular pages and categories.

Comment: Would those rules have to be written in a CSS preprocessor?

Comment: there is no CSS preprocessor :) funny! :) CSS is a runtime language, which is interpreted by the browser combined to its corresponding html tags/selectors

Comment: Right, but I'm familiar with preprocessors like SASS, though I've not used them. 

I guess I'm unclear about how to write rules that target variable pages / categories in a stylesheet.

Comment: Tom, many WP themes include javascript that adds classes to the body or html elements to denote what sort of page it is (i.e. single, category, archive, home, blog etc).  That way you can write CSS that selects specific content types without having to use PHP to enqueue additional stylesheets.  I think even the default themes have this functionality - I would look into this.

Comment: if you give in your templates #id in there placed content boxes like `<div id="..` or `<body id="..` you can have one plenty css-file which adresses all **and different** page-types or post-types or categories. so its clever to think about unique namespaces for `#id` or `.class`, it makes it even easier to have control over the template. think about where all the cpu load should run, at client side or at the server for every pageload